# Selenium: Drag & Drop into a SVG Element

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm trying to Drag a Webelement and drop it inside of a SVG "container" which has 4 elements in it, 4 polygons. Polygon 1 =g[1]  Polygon 2 =g[2] etc...

Here is the html code of this container:

```
<div class="leaflet-overlay-pane"><img class="leaflet-image-layer leaflet- 
zoom-animated" src="/ik-conf/layout/Planos1544448485901.png" style="opacity: 
1; transform: translate3d(509px, 280px, 0px); width: 524px; height: 348px;">
<svg class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="1472" height="855" viewBox="35 26 
1472 855" style="transform: translate3d(35px, 26px, 0px);">
<g><path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" 
stroke="#FF9900" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" fill="#FF9900" fill- 
opacity="0.2" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M714 300L709 586L529 591L533 
300z"></path></g>
<g><path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" 
stroke="#FF9900" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" fill="#FF9900" fill- 
opacity="0.2" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M1011 305L1009 585L802 589L797 
302z"></path></g>
<g><path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" 
stroke="#00FFD5" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" fill="#00FFD5" fill- 
opacity="0.2" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M690 444L688 554L544 552L544 
433z"></path></g>
<g><path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" 
stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" fill="#FFFFFF" fill- 
opacity="0.2" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M989 321L987 444L816 435L816 
320z"></path></g>
</svg><div class="leaflet-draw-guides"></div></div>
```

Each one of this Polygons (G's) is located by XPATH and/or CSS, and I'm always getting NoSuchElementException

This is the code I'm running:

```
public void dragAndDropPlanos(String nombre, WebElement poligono) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + nombre + "')]"), 1));
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + nombre + "')]"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + nombre + "')]"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element1));
//        WebElement target = poligono; 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(poligono));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + nombre + "')]"));
    (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element3, poligono).perform();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

So as you can see I'm passing as argument a string name I'm using to concatenate to a xpath to locate the element I want to drag, and also passing as a webelement the polygon where I want to drop to. As I said, these polygons are properly located and stored as weblement in a public class. I figured out that the svg may be placed in a different iframe, and I tried to switch, but it's not, it's just in a div, and I should be able to reach it through xpath

Anyone could bring some light here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you found incorrect WebElements due to too wide conditions and suspicious text.

```
  //*[contains(text(),'" + nombre + "')]
```

First, if you're looking for printable text, this locator will find nothing because there is no text in your SVG. Second, why do you looking for *any* element with text? Try to search by tag name first and check if it returns  tags.

```
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("g"));
```

Also, even if *g* element has been found, some drivers (i.e., PhantomJS) probably will not able to manipulate it, so you'll have to get internal element *(path)* to do that.